# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Lenovo G50 need support [amdgpu, radeon]

Tags: drivers, xorg, 22.04, radeon

i need some support. I would like to ask you about, what can i do with my laptop drivers? I can't setup my Hybrid graphics. I read tons of manuals, and how-tos, but still unable to start it up. If i change **amdgpu** to radeon driver in xorg.conf, the output will be the same.

So. I have **Ubuntu 22.04 LTS** with **5.15.0-52-generic** #58-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 13 08:03:55 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux,

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
    03:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun LE [Radeon HD 8550M / R5 M230]
   

  Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: AMD Sun LE [Radeon HD 8550M / R5 M230] driver: amdgpu
    v: 5.16.9.22.20
  Device-3: Acer Lenovo EasyCamera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: intel
    unloaded: amdgpu gpu: i915 resolution: 1366x768~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 22.0.5

    [xatrix@MERNOV-NB ~]$ sudo dkms status
    amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04, 5.15.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed

[xatrix@MERNOV-NB ~]$ dmesg -t | grep amdgpu
Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-52-generic root=UUID=335fdad2-293f-4e34-b6ba-889b6f4ec3af ro ipv6.disable=1 net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 usbcore.autosuspend=-1 pci=noaer radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.dc=1 iommu=soft
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-52-generic root=UUID=335fdad2-293f-4e34-b6ba-889b6f4ec3af ro ipv6.disable=1 net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 usbcore.autosuspend=-1 pci=noaer radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.dc=1 iommu=soft
[drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[drm] amdgpu version: 5.16.9.22.20
amdgpu: vga_switcheroo: detected switching method \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0.ATPX handle
amdgpu: CRAT table not found
amdgpu: Virtual CRAT table created for CPU
amdgpu: Topology: Add CPU node
amdgpu: PeerDirect support was initialized successfully
amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Trusted Memory Zone (TMZ) feature not supported
kfd kfd: amdgpu: HAINAN  not supported in kfd
amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Fetched VBIOS from ATRM
amdgpu: ATOM BIOS: 113-xxx-Xxx
amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: PCIE atomic ops is not supported
amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VRAM: 2048M 0x000000F400000000 - 0x000000F47FFFFFFF (2048M used)
amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GART: 256M 0x000000FF00000000 - 0x000000FF0FFFFFFF
[drm] amdgpu: 2048M of VRAM memory ready
[drm] amdgpu: 7840M of GTT memory ready.
amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: PCIE GART of 256M enabled (table at 0x000000F400000000).
[drm] amdgpu: dpm initialized
amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SE 1, SH per SE 1, CU per SH 5, active_cu_number 4
amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Using BOCO for runtime pm
[drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.46.0 20150101 for 0000:03:00.0 on minor 0

[xatrix@MERNOV-NB ~]$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[    13.336]
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.3
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    13.336] Current Operating System: Linux MERNOV-NB 5.15.0-52-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 13 08:03:55 UTC 2022 x86_64
[    13.336] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-52-generic root=UUID=335fdad2-293f-4e34-b6ba-889b6f4ec3af ro ipv6.disable=1 net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 usbcore.autosuspend=-1 pci=noaer radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.dc=1 iommu=soft
[    13.336] xorg-server 2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
[    13.336] Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
[    13.336]     Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    13.336] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    13.336] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Nov  5 19:57:18 2022
[    13.345] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    13.345] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    13.350] (==) ServerLayout "X.org Configured"
[    13.350] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[    13.350] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[    13.353] (**) |   |-->Device "Card0"
[    13.353] (**) |-->Screen "Screen1" (1)
[    13.353] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor1"
[    13.353] (**) |   |-->Device "Card1"
[    13.353] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[    13.353] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[    13.353] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    13.353] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    13.354] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    13.354] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[    13.354] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    13.368] (**) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[    13.368] (**) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    13.368] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[    13.368] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[    13.368] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[    13.368] (II) Loader magic: 0x55cf8b852020
[    13.368] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    13.368]     X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    13.368]     X.Org Video Driver: 25.2
[    13.368]     X.Org XInput driver : 24.4
[    13.368]     X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    13.370] (++) using VT number 7

[    13.370] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[    13.372] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[    13.372] (II) Platform probe for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1
[    13.381] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    13.381] (II) Platform probe for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:03:00.0/drm/card0
[    13.393] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 8086:0a16:17aa:380c rev 11, Mem @ 0xd0000000/4194304, 0xc0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00006000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    13.393] (--) PCI: (3@0:0:0) 1002:666f:17aa:380c rev 0, Mem @ 0xb0000000/268435456, 0xd0400000/262144, I/O @ 0x00003000/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    13.397] (II) "glx" will be loaded. This was enabled by default and also specified in the config file.
[    13.397] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    13.403] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    13.413] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    13.413]     compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    13.413]     ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[    13.413] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    13.413] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    13.427] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    13.427]     compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 2.99.917
[    13.427]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    13.427]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[    13.427] (II) LoadModule: "amdgpu"
[    13.427] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so
[    13.445] (II) Module amdgpu: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    13.445]     compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 22.0.0
[    13.445]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    13.445]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[    13.445] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[    13.445] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics
[    13.445] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics
[    13.445] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics
[    13.445] (II) AMDGPU: Driver for AMD Radeon:
    All GPUs supported by the amdgpu kernel driver
[    13.473] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20201103
[    13.473] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.917+git20210115-1 (Timo Aaltonen <tjaalton@debian.org>)
[    13.473] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled for use with valgrind
[    13.489] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4400
[    13.489] (--) intel(0): CPU: x86-64, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, avx, avx2; using a maximum of 2 threads
[    13.489] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    13.489] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[    13.489] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    13.493] (II) intel(0): Output eDP1 using monitor section Monitor0
[    13.493] (**) intel(0): Found backlight control interface intel_backlight (type 'raw') for output eDP1
[    13.494] (II) intel(0): Enabled output eDP1
[    13.494] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI1 has no monitor section
[    13.494] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI1
[    13.494] (II) intel(0): Output DP1 has no monitor section
[    13.494] (II) intel(0): Enabled output DP1
[    13.494] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI2 has no monitor section
[    13.494] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI2
[    13.494] (--) intel(0): Using a maximum size of 256x256 for hardware cursors
[    13.495] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 has no monitor section
[    13.495] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VIRTUAL1
[    13.495] (--) intel(0): Output eDP1 using initial mode 1366x768 on pipe 0
[    13.495] (==) intel(0): TearFree disabled
[    13.495] (==) intel(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    13.495] (==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    13.495] (II) Loading sub module "dri3"
[    13.495] (II) LoadModule: "dri3"
[    13.495] (II) Module "dri3" already built-in
[    13.495] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    13.495] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    13.495] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    13.495] (II) Loading sub module "present"
[    13.495] (II) LoadModule: "present"
[    13.495] (II) Module "present" already built-in
[    13.496] (==) AMDGPU(1): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    13.496] (II) AMDGPU(1): Pixel depth = 24 bits stored in 4 bytes (32 bpp pixmaps)
[    13.496] (==) AMDGPU(1): Default visual is TrueColor
[    13.496] (==) AMDGPU(1): RGB weight 888
[    13.496] (II) AMDGPU(1): Using 8 bits per RGB (8 bit DAC)
[    13.496] (--) AMDGPU(1): Chipset: "AMD Radeon HD 8500M" (ChipID = 0x666f)
[    13.496] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    13.496] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    13.496] (II) Module "fb" already built-in
[    13.496] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    13.496] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    13.496] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    14.051] (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
[    14.051] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[    14.051] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[    14.067] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    14.067]     compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 1.0.1
[    14.067]     ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    14.138] (II) AMDGPU(1): glamor X acceleration enabled on AMD Radeon HD 8500M (hainan, LLVM 13.0.1, DRM 3.46, 5.15.0-52-generic)
[    14.138] (II) AMDGPU(1): glamor detected, initialising EGL layer.
[    14.138] (==) AMDGPU(1): TearFree property default: auto
[    14.138] (==) AMDGPU(1): VariableRefresh: disabled
[    14.138] (==) AMDGPU(1): AsyncFlipSecondaries: disabled
[    14.138] (II) AMDGPU(1): KMS Pageflipping: enabled
[    14.138] (WW) AMDGPU(1): No outputs definitely connected, trying again...
[    14.138] (WW) AMDGPU(1): Unable to find connected outputs - setting 1024x768 initial framebuffer
[    14.138] (II) AMDGPU(1): mem size init: gart size :1e9db0000 vram size: s:7f77d000 visible:ff7d000
[    14.138] (==) AMDGPU(1): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    14.138] (==) AMDGPU(1): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    14.138] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    14.138] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    14.138] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    14.138] (EE) AMDGPU(1): No modes.
[    14.141] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    14.141] (II) UnloadSubModule: "glamoregl"
[    14.141] (II) Unloading glamoregl
[    14.147] (II) intel(0): SNA initialized with Haswell (gen7.5, gt2) backend
[    14.147] (==) intel(0): Backing store enabled
[    14.147] (==) intel(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    14.149] (II) intel(0): HW Cursor enabled
[    14.151] (==) intel(0): DPMS enabled
[    14.151] (==) intel(0): Display hotplug detection enabled
[    14.152] (II) intel(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    14.152] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[    14.152] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: va_gl
[    14.152] (II) intel(0): direct rendering: DRI2 enabled
[    14.152] (II) intel(0): hardware support for Present enabled
[    14.152] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
[    14.152] (II) Initializing extension SHAPE
[    14.152] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SHM
[    14.153] (II) Initializing extension XInputExtension
[    14.153] (II) Initializing extension XTEST
[    14.154] (II) Initializing extension BIG-REQUESTS
[    14.154] (II) Initializing extension SYNC
[    14.154] (II) Initializing extension XKEYBOARD
[    14.154] (II) Initializing extension XC-MISC
[    14.155] (II) Initializing extension SECURITY
[    14.155] (II) Initializing extension XFIXES
[    14.155] (II) Initializing extension RENDER
[    14.155] (II) Initializing extension RANDR
[    14.156] (II) Initializing extension COMPOSITE
[    14.156] (II) Initializing extension DAMAGE
[    14.156] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    14.157] (II) Initializing extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    14.157] (II) Initializing extension RECORD
[    14.157] (II) Initializing extension DPMS
[    14.157] (II) Initializing extension Present
[    14.158] (II) Initializing extension DRI3
[    14.158] (II) Initializing extension X-Resource
[    14.158] (II) Initializing extension XVideo
[    14.158] (II) Initializing extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    14.158] (II) Initializing extension SELinux
[    14.158] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    14.158] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[    14.271] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized i965
[    14.271] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[    14.271] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    14.271] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
[    14.271] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
[    14.271] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
[    14.285] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1366x768@60.0 on eDP1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[    14.297] (II) intel(0): Setting screen physical size to 361 x 203
[    14.420] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[    14.420] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    14.420] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[    14.420] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
```

Comment: So what is the problem? `amdgpu` is the correct driver.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't detect the screen output, so the driver can't enable itself on my system